# GitLab CI building on multiple runners

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, gitlab

My question is relatively simple,

I have gitlab set-up, gitlab CI too and two separate server which each have their own runner.
Both runners are working and can execute a build successfully.

What I'd like to achieve now is to have one project be build by both runners, perferrably even with seperate commands. This last thing doesn't seem possible however if I add both runners to a project it just seems to build on one of them and not the other.

Is it possible to get it to build on both and maybe even vary the scripts?

Comment: I have the same issue.. I noticed that now its possible to assign multiple runners to the same project, but it runs only at one runner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone brought this up on the GitLab CI issue tracker (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci/issues/237). The workaround proposed there is as follows:

> Create multiple jobs with different tags and assign different tags to these runners:
>   
>   `job1:
>     script: echo 1
>     tags:
>     - runner1
>   job2:
>     script: echo 2
>     tags:
>     - runner2`

Not a great solution, especially if you want to run the exact same job on a bunch of runners (as I do), but it can be made to work.

Comment: This question is no longer relevant to me, but since this answer would have satisfied my original requirements, be it a bit hack-ish, I'm marking it as accepted.